# How to use flatMap() and reduce() on a range of a 2d array

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix, multidimensional-array, flatten

I'm having a 2d array and I want to use something similar to flatMap and reduce together with a range of each of the two dimension. In my example I want to add each number from position 1 to 3 in each row 0 to 2.

My code at the moment looks similar to the following and it does work.

```
let array = [
     [3,6,8,4],
     [3,7,4,6],
     [2,4,5,7],
     [5,3,7,4]
]

let row = 1
let col = 2
var reducedValue = 0        
        
(row-1...row+1).forEach {
     reducedValue = array[$0][col-1...col+1].compactMap { $0 }.reduce(reducedValue, +)
}
```

The expected output is:

```
51
//6 + 8 + 4 + 7 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 5 + 7
```

However I was wondering if there is a solution similar to the this one:

```
reducedValue = array[row-1...row+1][col-1...col+1].compactMap { $0 }.reduce(0, +)
```

Or maybe even without the compactMap similar to this:

```
reducedValue = array[row-1...row+1][col-1...col+1].reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Please give both input (which you have) and desired output.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks! : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could flatten the array of arrays and then `reduce` that. For example:

```
let total = array[row-1...row+1]
    .flatMap { $0[col-1...col+1] }
    .reduce(0, +)
```

That yields:

> 51

---

If you wanted to avoid the overhead of building that flattened array (which is immaterial unless dealing with very large subarrays, i.e., millions of values), you can perform the calculation lazily:

```
let total = array[row-1...row+1]
    .lazy
    .flatMap { $0[col-1...col+1] }
    .reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which adds the values of the selected rows and columns without creating an intermediate array:

```
let value = array[row-1...row+1].reduce(0, { $0 + $1[col-1...col+1].reduce(0, +) })
print(value) // 51
```

The outer `reduce()` iterates over the selected rows and adds for each row the sum of the values of the values in the selected columns, which are computed in the inner `reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

While the functional approach would give you the most succinct code

```swift
let result = array[row-1...row+1].reduce(into: 0) { $0 += $1[col-1...col+1].reduce(into: 0, +=) }
```

, the classic imperative code should not be ignored:

```
var result = 0
for i in row-1...row+1 {
    for j in col-1...col+1 {
        result += array[i][j]
    }
}
```

The imperative approach, though more verbose and not 100% Swift idiomatic (uses a `var` when a `let` alternative exists), is more readable in this particular context, of processing mathematical concepts.

Comment: I do like the imperative code as well in terms of understanding and readability. However my original code was already embedded in pretty much two similar for-in loops to iterate over the 2d array. And store each value in a new 2d array. That would have meant 4 levels of for-in loops. :)

Comment: @MarcoBoerner, yeah, 4 level of for loops are not nice at all. You might want to split that logic in two: computing the 2d arrays, computing the sum for each 2d array, regardless of the sum computation approach you take (functional or imperative)